# Convert time to users local zone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Trying to format/parse the following date stamp from the server into the users local time zone using momentjs library.

Added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hgyb490/

I've tried

`moment.utc(date)`

`moment(date).format(<format>)`

`moment.utc(date).local()`

My time string from the server looks like this:
`2015-08-17T15:33:00`

My filter looks like:

```
var angular = require("angular");

module.exports = function filter (ngModule) {

  // Filter =================================================================

  var filterName = "localTime";

  ngModule.filter( "localTime", function (moment)
  {
      return ( function( date )
      {
          debugger;
          var formattedLocalTime = moment(date).local().format( "h:mma M/d/YYYY" );

          return formattedLocalTime;
      } );

  } );

  return filterName;
};
```

I've also tried the following, but seems inconsistent:

```
  var testDateUtc = moment.utc(date);
  var localDate = moment(testDateUtc).local();
  var formattedLocalTime = localDate.format("h:mma M/d/YYYY");

  return formattedLocalTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

`d` lowercase is a *day of the week* (check: `localDate.day() === 4`).

You need an uppercase `D` for *day of the month* (`localDate.date() === 2`).

http://jsfiddle.net/2hgyb490/1/

Comment: Still getting some weird issues, if I enter 1:00am, it renders as 12:00PM. According to my server guy, the timestamp is correct. I'l try to update it with the time string.